# Gunicorn worker critical time out (using with flask)

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn, gevent

I am getting Gunicorn critical worker timeout which I can solve with increasing the timeout, however, that doesn't seem the right way as it might take more than an hour for the threads to complete certain tasks.

My server:
At the start, it computes specific NLP tasks using Google Word2Vec model. Once this is done, it starts responding to HTTP get/put requests to do the relevant processing. The server starts multiple threads as soon as it starts and blocks on join for the threads to complete these tasks. Its difficult to put the exact code here. However, it does something like this:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = queue.Queue()
threads = []
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()

# stop workers
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    q.put(None)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Dowork is the NLP task which takes around 1-2 seconds. Now if there are 10 tasks then I can set the timeout to 20 seconds and it works fine (assuming I am running one thread). However, if I crease the tasks then I get the critical timeout error. I have thousands of these tasks which needs to be done before the server start serve requests.

part of the command I run:

```
gunicorn -t 240 -k gevent .......
```

One way is the increase timeout to an 3 hours which should be fine  but I don't think if thatś recommend. What is my alternative here? How can I make the threads announce to the relevant arbiter that the workers are alive so they are not killed?

Comment: Is it possible to go deeper? As in, separating gunicorn and the NLP work in two processes and using systemd, if you're using a common linux distro, to run both processes, with one being dependent on the other.

Comment: For now, that's not possible. I resolved the issue by sleeping for a few milliseconds each time a thread does its task so it can notify the master that its still alive.